# Query operation in Mongodb to find intersection between two dataset from the same collection

Tags: mongodb

I am new in Mongo and need help to form the query to retrieve following information from mongodb collection

Say I have a collection that holds association of users with groups. Users can be assigned to some groups. In the following following example I want to find out the users who are part of group (1 OR 2) AND group 3, which will return user1 for the following data. Though user2 and user3 are part of group 1 and group 2 respectiveky, it will not be returned as they are not part of group 3

---

```
{
_id : NumberLong(1),
user : "user1",
group : NumberLong(1),
}
{
_id : NumberLong(2),
user : "user1",
group : NumberLong(2),
}
{
_id : NumberLong(3),
user : "user1",
group : NumberLong(3),
}
{
_id : NumberLong(1),
user : "user2",
group : NumberLong(1),
}
{
_id : NumberLong(1),
user : "user3",
group : NumberLong(2),
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing about your question is that the 5 documents can not be inserted in a single collection because 3 documents have same value of `_id` field and as this `_id` field is primary key in mongodb, so it can't be repeated for a single collection. So by inserting below data in the collection,

```
 { "_id" : NumberLong(1), "user" : "user1", "group" : NumberLong(1) }
 { "_id" : NumberLong(2), "user" : "user1", "group" : NumberLong(2) }
 { "_id" : NumberLong(3), "user" : "user1", "group" : NumberLong(3) }
 { "_id" : NumberLong(4), "user" : "user2", "group" : NumberLong(1) } 
 { "_id" : NumberLong(5), "user" : "user3", "group" : NumberLong(2) }
```

you can use mongodb aggregation framework to find out all the users that belongs to either group 1 or 2 and group 3. The query for this would be

```
  db.user.aggregate({
   $group: {
             _id: "$user",
              grouping: { $addToSet: "$group"} } },
           {  $match: { 
                     $and: [
                            { $or: [{ grouping: { $in: [1,2]}}]},
                            { grouping: 3}
                            ]}});
```

Comment: Thanks joao and Vijay for your help on this. Vijay, I am sorry about that for having duplicate primary key in my example. The solution you provided worked perfectly fine for me. joao, the distinct operation with $and and $or clause didn't work for me. It gave empty result

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as this:

```
db.colection.distinct('user', {$and : [{$or : [{group : 1}, {group : 2}]}, {group : 3}]});
```

You can check the mongodb docs section about the [logical operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query-logical/). And the [distinct](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/).